# prepend domain-search is overwriting rather than prepending

Tags: linux, networking, dns, resolv.conf

I have an Linux host running on AWS and I want to add a domain to the search. By default, the resolv.conf file looks like this

```
[ec2-user@ip- ~]$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
search us-west-2.compute.internal
```

I tried adding the following line to `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

```
prepend domain-search "ux.corp.local";
```

The resulting resolv.conf file (after restarting network) looks like this.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-30-39 ~]$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
search ux.corp.local.
```

It obviously didn't prepend (I tried append too). It also didn't put the domain in correctly (see the period at the end).

How can I prepend or append a domain to search in resolv.conf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It obviously didn't prepend (I tried append too)

Note that there are *two* DHCP options for this: `domain-name` (which contains one domain suffix and is also used for slightly different purposes) and `domain-search` (which contains multiple suffixes).

I suspect your *current* value "us-west-2.compute.internal" actually comes from the `domain-name` option, and `domain-search` is actually empty. So when you prepend or append to it, dhclient sees that both options are now set, and ignores `domain-name` (as it's older and more limited).

So you'll need to either manually list both domains, or alter the resolv.conf generation step. For example, many distros use `resolvconf` (aka openresolv) as an intermediary tool which generates resolv.conf from several sources, and it supports a `search_domains_append=` option to add custom suffixes on top of DHCP data.

> It also didn't put the domain in correctly (see the period at the end).

No, that's still correct. A trailing period indicates a fully-qualified domain name (just like a leading slash would indicate an absolute path). When you try to resolve a domain which *doesn't* have trailing period, the OS may try appending all search suffixes to it. (Yes, even if the name already consists of multiple components!)

Of course, in the search list *itself*, the trailing dot changes absolutely nothing. But since the idea of a search list is "if you append this, you'll get a fully-qualified domain", some people find it quite logical to put fully-qualified suffixes in `search`. (Or maybe they're just being pedantic.)